# Basic concept of stack and interrupt

Tags: stack, interrupt

I have a question for the concept of stack and interrupt in specific situation.
When multiple interrupt happend, current location of memory is saved in stack in order
My question is..
If 3 interrupts occur and stack have only 2 space to store a current location of memory
Then, what happend after storing 2 memory location in stack??

Comment: "Stack" and "interrupt" are two almost totally unrelated concepts.  Stacks are sometimes used for handling interrupts, but probably more often not.

Comment: In terms of what happens if there are 3 interrupts and only two places to save state, either 1) the machine crashes, or 2) the third interrupt is not "serviced" until space to save state is available.

Answer (score 0):

If your stack has room for only 2 entries, and you push 3 items on the stack, you get a stackoverflow.

(Does this question belong on meta? ;)